# Querying a SharePoint list and typesetting the response with LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, automation

I would like to generate some reports from data stored in SharePoint lists. It is possible to query the lists using web services and retrieve the data in a xml data format.

For example, sending a request to my SharePoint site using the following `curl` commad

```
curl --ntlm --user "user:pass" -H "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --data @request.txt --output answer.txt http://intranet/_vti_bin/lists.asmx
```

With a `request.txt` file containing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap12:Body>
        <GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
            <listName>Test</listName>
            <query>
                <Query>
                    <Where>
                        <IsNotNull>
                            <FieldRef Name="Title" />
                        </IsNotNull>
                    </Where>
                </Query>
            </query>
            <viewFields>
                <ViewFields>
                    <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                    <FieldRef Name='Day' />
                </ViewFields>
            </viewFields>
            <QueryOptions>
                <IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>
                <ViewFieldsOnly>TRUE</ViewFieldsOnly>
            </QueryOptions>
        </GetListItems>
    </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

returns an answer from my test list in SharePoint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <soap:Body>
        <GetListItemsResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
            <GetListItemsResult>
                <listitems 
                    xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
                    xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
                    xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
                    xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
                    <rs:data ItemCount="3">
                        <z:row ows_Title='Yesterday' ows_Day='2014-04-13 00:00:00' />
                        <z:row ows_Title='Today' ows_Day='2014-04-14 00:00:00' />
                        <z:row ows_Title='Tomorrow' ows_Day='2014-04-15 00:00:00' />
                    </rs:data>
                </listitems>
            </GetListItemsResult>
        </GetListItemsResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Is it possible to send such a request directly from LuaLaTeX and process the response as part of the typesetting process? I know I can write the request to a file using the `filecontents` package and wrap the `curl` call in `\immediate\write18{curl ...}` but I was wondering if a better way exists that take advantage of additional features from LuaLaTeX?

From Google I have found that LuaTeX has `luasocket` build in, and `luaxml` from the `odsfile` package also seems relevant. However, I have no idea how to start using these tools. Therefore my question: Is it possible to query a SharePoint list (or some other web service that returns data in xml format) and parse the result using LuaLaTeX?

Comment: *Is it possible to send such a request directly from LuaLaTeX* -- Yes, but you’re going to have to use an SSL wrapper like [``luasec``](https://github.com/brunoos/luasec) to make the requests. Or call the ``curl`` binary using ``os.execute()`` like Context does. Then use the XML library of your choice to extract the data and process it like any normal document. I’ve never used Sharepoint so I can’t help you with the details.

Comment: Thanks. However, this is basically similar to my current approach with the `curl` call in `\immediate\write18` and a piped input using `xmlstarlet` to extract what I need from the SharePoint response xml. I was hoping that a more self contained solution existed that only relied on the `LuaLaTeX` executable and preferably only additional tools in TeXlive or things that can easily ship with the document.

Comment: If you could drop the hard requirement on Latex, Context should be able to do it out of the box: It too uses ``curl`` transparently and comes with a builtin XML parser. Sorry I can’t help you any further.

Comment: I haven't tried Context before, but I would be very interested in some pointers if anybody has tried something similar to what I am attempting in Context.